# Find max for values of the same group and indicate the value in a seperate column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the max in the second column when they belong to the same group defined in the first column and write the maximum value on a third column on the same line as it appears in column 2.

I wrote a piece of code but can't get further.

```
Sub MarkMax()

Dim i As Double
Dim x As Double

For i = 1 To 1000
For x = 1 To 4

If Cells(i, 1) = x Then

Cells(i, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Cells(i, 2))

End If

Next x
Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use VBA for such a simple task?

Comment: This is not my actual data, just a representation of the problem due to confidentiality. I have 6000 lines of data...

Comment: 6000 lines of data is not a lot on a grand scheme of things. Nothing `MAXIFS()` can't handle.

Comment: Are you just getting the max of one cell as well?

Comment: Yes I thought of that. Most important thing, though, is not to find the maximum but to mark its position (like I did with column 3). Then, for each group, I need to find the position and find the line and mark it. I thought I could automate this and also wanted to learn vba.

Comment: Then use conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

No reason for using VBA for that. As explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-7881d256-b4fa-4f81-b71e-b0a3d4a52b3a) there is a basic feature, subtotals, which covers this.

Obviously, as a function, don't use `SUM` or `AVERAGE`, but `MAX`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don' need VBA for this. If I were you I **would create a table to make the formulas dynamic** when you enter new rows.

Supposing that your column headers are in A1:C1 and that you have only 20 rows paste this in first cell of MAX column and copy down.

```
=IF(MAXIFS($B$2:$B$20;$A$2:$A$20;A2)=B2;MAXIFS($B$2:$B$20;$A$2:$A$20;A2);"")
```

Comment: No need to repeat the `MAXIFS` function.  You can simplify to just `=IF(MAXIFS([Value],[Group],[@Group])=[@Value],[@Value],"")`